# In a case of a item trading style site, how should I store and read data? (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to make a little Web App to be used along with a Game Server.

The web app should allow users to view a series of offerings/requests of in game items. The offerings and requests come from user input into the site.

My question here is what is the best best way store the data from these user inputs and then use this stored data to generate some kind of listing page.

In case you want some details the following will explain what exactly the user input fields will be:

- **Item Name** *(string)*
- **Item Amount** *(int)*
- **Per Item Cost** *(double/decimal)*

Also there would be a view things like the Username of person, the offering/request ID (which could just be an auto incrementing field like in a database).

**Considering that I am pretty new to storing information and retrieving it, what would be the easiest way to store it compared to the best (efficient) way to store it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store your data in a database. I hear they're great for this sort of thing.

Helpful tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Comment: And would this be the easiest way for a new user?

Comment: Though I already new that a Database was most likely the best option, I guess my question was pretty dumb. The link you gave though was worth it. I have skimmed over some of the tutorials there and they seem to be VERY helpful. Thanks!

Comment: They're the tutorials I used when I first started learning how to use MySQL / PHP. Have fun!